# Markov Chain State Transition Probability in R

Tags: time-series, probability, markov-chain

I have a dataset which shows the states (3 states) across 11 time points for each participant. I wanted to estimate the Markov Chain state transition probability matrices for time points 2-11 using R. I read both `markovchain` and `HiddenMarkov` package documentations, but did not see any examples similar to what I planned to do. The most relevant example is the one listed under `MarkovchainFit` (in `markovchian` package), but it seems to me the data entry is a sequence of states (not a sequence of states for an each individual participant), and there is only one transition matrix calculated. I appreciate any suggestions. That is also great if any other statistical software can support the calculation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The current version of markovchain package has implemented a function to address your issue.

```
library(markovchain)
data(holson)
mcListFist<-markovchainListFit(data=holson[,2:12],name="holson")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
trans.matrix <- function(chain)  {
  states <- length(unique(chain))
  p <- matrix(nrow = states, ncol = states, 0) # initialise transition matrix
  for (t in 1:(length(chain) - 1)){ p[chain[t], chain[t + 1]] <- p[chain[t], chain[t + 1]] + 1}
  for (i in 1:states) p[i, ] <- p[i, ] / sum(p[i, ]) # make stochastic
  return (p)
}

chain <- c (1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1) 
trans.matrix(chain)
```

Answer (score 1):

One may simpy use the library markovchain.

```
    library(markovchain)
    timeseq <- c (1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1) 
    markovchainFit(as.character(timeseq ))
```